# jQuery Selector & Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to make a selector to scrape a pinterest image.  The selector I made grabs the first version of the selector which is an avatar wrapped in its own div.  I want to grab the 2nd instance of the selector which is the actual image

This is my selector:
`("meta[itemprop = 'image']").attr('content');`

This what I want to get
`<meta itemprop="image" content="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/11/9d/fa/119dfa7dbf8ba60e694f994e38c0622b.jpg">`

Here is the pinterest page link I'm attempting to scrape:
`https://www.pinterest.com/pin/374784000210632724/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you want to grab the second occurence of $("meta[itemprop = 'image']")

In that case you must grab that specific instance, for example like this:

```
var domElem = $("meta[itemprop = 'image']").get(1);
```

And then you grab the attribute content like you wrote above:

```
var content = $(domElem).attr('content');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it faster with `eq(i)`.
If you want the second element:

```
$("meta[itemprop = 'image']").eq(1).attr('content');
```

[Link to the doc](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/tree/c0096b150c01303f7e15d584e3a1648f52bd63c4#eq-i-)